# How to install envoy proxy on redhat 7

Tags: linux, proxy, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I follow envoy doc https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/install to how to install Envoy proxy : but I keep getting the same error:

```
rpm --import 'https://rpm.dl.getenvoy.io/public/gpg.CF716AF503183491.key'

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2600:9000:2199:9a00:1:3749:30c0:93a1: Network is unreachable
error: https://rpm.dl.getenvoy.io/public/gpg.CF716AF503183491.key: import read failed(2).
```

I also tried to disable and enable firewall , keep getting the same error.

If anyone have any suggestion please help.

Comment: Assume RHEL 7.x ( not the ~20 year old Redhat 7 ) : No issues now with the `rpm --import` command , please try again.

Comment: Thx for trying to reply , It is not about the version , I am getting the same error. I am installing it on high secure environment